# In the movie, Stranger By the Lake, why did the heavy guy (Eric) lead the killer on?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-by-the-lake

In Strangers By the Lake, why did Eric (Patrick d'Assumçao) confront Michel with accusations, and then entice him into the woods, knowing he was a killer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was Henri who did that, and he did it because he wanted to die.

Patrick d'Assumcao played a character named Henri, not Eric. He was depressed and was suicidal. He purposely lured the killer into the woods because he wanted the killer to kill him. Henri tells Franck that it's better this way, or something to that effect.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher This absolutely was an answer to the question. Just because it was brief and lacking in detail doesn't make it not an answer.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: At the moment when I flagged this answer, it was a one-line answer, rather more like a passing comment. My motive was to only attract the attention of the answerer to enhance and clarify it. All credit to user iandotkelly who has put in an effort to make it appropriate and acceptable.

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher Yes, I looked at the revision history to see what it looked like when you flagged it. The flag was still inappropriate. Flags are for attracting moderator attention. If you just want to get the answerer's attention, leave a comment and/or vote.

Comment: @ChrisHayes: It was ultimately by attracting one of the moderator's attention that it is more of a proper answer now. Or would you prefer the answer in its previous form and the question languishing in an open state?

Comment: @KeyBrdBasher The fact that a moderator was kind enough to edit the answer to a better state doesn't mean the flag was appropriate. You could have (and perhaps should have) made the exact same edit yourself, or asked the answerer to do it. Again: that is *not* the purpose of Not An Answer flags.

Comment: I came across this question while searching the Internet for more information about the movie. I saw no one had answered it, so I threw in my apparently-too-short answer, which was also addressing the fact that the original question was flawed, since it named the wrong character from the film. Even though my answer was correct, it was brief, and it got flagged and voted down. After writng a longer answer, I got voted down again. Some days it doesn't pay to try to help out. Thanks again Chris. I'll be deleting my account now and the rest of you can carry on with your rules and flagging.